# Noise when streaming in openal

Tags: audio-streaming, openal

I'd like to stream audio using openal (linux), but what I get is noise and some of the song in background.
I read 4-channel ambisonic file and discard 2 channels. 
I am sending 20000 frames to openal buffer (20000 * 2_channels * 4 bytes).

Can't tell what is wrong. I think that this code is correct.
The part which is responsible for loading chunk of the audio file and converting it into 2 channeled is good, because I've tested it. I've written output to a file and got good quality 2-channel wav.

Ambisonic file has 4 channels and 48kHz samplerate. I've created openal context without additional parameters.

Any suggestions?

```
const int NUM_BUFFERS = 2;
const int BUFFER_SIZE = 20000;      // frames
ALuint source, buffers[NUM_BUFFERS];

int streamBuffer(ALuint bufID, int bufferSize, AudioFile &audio) {
    const SF_INFO &info = audio.getInfo();
    const lli numFrames = bufferSize;

    float *bufHrtf = new float[bufferSize * 2];
    float *buf = nullptr;
    audio.readFrames(numFrames, &buf);

    lli idxHrtf = 0;
    for (lli j = 0; j < numFrames * info.channels; j += info.channels) {  
        bufHrtf[idxHrtf++] =  buf[j + 1];
        bufHrtf[idxHrtf++] = buf[j + 2];
    }

    alBufferData(bufID, AL_FORMAT_STEREO16, bufHrtf, idxHrtf * sizeof(float), info.samplerate);
    delete [] bufHrtf;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    AudioFile audio;
    if (!audio.open("sample.amb")) {
        return 1;
    }

    if (!createOpenAlAndBuffer()) {
        return 1;
    }

    streamBuffer(buffers[0], BUFFER_SIZE, audio);
    streamBuffer(buffers[1], BUFFER_SIZE, audio);
    alSourceQueueBuffers(source, 2, buffers);

    alSourcePlay(source);
    while(!audio.endOfFile())
    {
        // Check how much data is processed in OpenAL's internal queue
        ALint processed{0};
        alGetSourcei(source, AL_BUFFERS_PROCESSED, &processed);

        // add more buffers while we need them
        while (processed--)
        {
            ALuint bufID;
            alSourceUnqueueBuffers(source, 1, &bufID);
            streamBuffer(bufID, BUFFER_SIZE, audio);
            alSourceQueueBuffers(source, 1, &bufID);

            int val{0};
            alGetSourcei(source, AL_SOURCE_STATE, &val);
            if(val != AL_PLAYING) {
                alSourcePlay(source);
            }
        }
    }

    destroyOpenAl();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Found answer

My data is in floats so there is need of:

```
#include <AL/alext.h>
```

and as a format in alBufferData to use

```
AL_FORMAT_STEREO_FLOAT32
```

Comment: Had same problem, this simple problem fixed it. I had data with 32-bit float PCM, and assumed libsndfile would convert the data properly (as it states in the documentation), but was not the case. Using the native format works perfectly.